# Project Status Table derivation SQL logic

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, case

```
Just sample entries

proj    stat   Inact
----------------------
PROJ1   I0002   
PROJ1   I0001   
PROJ2   I0042   X
PROJ3   I0046   X
PROJ3   I0045   
PROJ4   I0001   X
PROJ5   I0001   X
PROJ6   I0001   X
```

- If any of I0001 OR I0002 OR I0042 is Active ( Inact = blank), then it
  is OPEN.
- If any of I0045 OR I0046 is Active( means Inact = blank or
  entry doesnt exist), then it is CLOSED.
- Both 1 and 2 condition should satisfy
- Also If the above 5 status doesnt exists for any particular
  Proj then also it is OPEN by default

How can i derive the Project status (OPEN,CLOSE)?Please help.

proj    stat are the primary keys.

Comment: How do you know if something is active?

Comment: if Inact field is not set then it means those technical Stats are active. using this tech stats again i need to derive the another human understandable status Open or Close for this various combination mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation with conditional logic:

```
select proj,
       (case when sum(case when stat in ('I0001', 'I0002', 'I0042') and inact is null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'open'
             when sum(case when stat in ('I0045', 'I0046') and inact is null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'closed'
             else 'open'
        end) as status
from t
group by proj
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon.I tested and i am getting everything 'open'

Comment: Thanks Gordon.I just investigated and found inact is null be replaced with inact = ' '  and it worked thank you very much.I really appreciate your help a lot.